# Cannot load timestamp into MySQL table using LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql, timestamp, load

Input data looks like this:

```
Incident ID,CR Number,Dispatch Date / Time
201073514,16016688,04/05/2016 10:07:48 PM
201073496,16016678,04/05/2016 08:53:35 PM
...
201073481,16016656,04/05/2016 06:47:01 PM
```

After running load

```
LOAD DATA  INFILE 'C:\\Temp\\orders.csv' INTO TABLE orders
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I tried different `Dispatch_Date_Time`  types like DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP but it always comes out as zero:

```
mysql> select Dispatch_Date_Time from orders limit 5;
+---------------------+
| Dispatch_Date_Time  |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the STR_TO_DATE function? Looks like you need to add a line at the end using that to store it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use it like this:

```
LOAD DATA  INFILE 'C:\\Temp\\orders.csv'
INTO TABLE orders
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(c1, c2, @c3)
SET c3 = STR_TO_DATE(@c3,'%d/%m/%Y %I:%i:%s %p');
```

Comment: @Alex B - Sorry i has an error in my answer and have correct it. i have not seen AM/PM

Comment: For that I need to know the column names and types.